# How can I query on a referenced field in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reference, mongodb-query, dereference

I have two collections, `users` and `posts`. The relevant parts of a typical document looks like this:

**user**

```
{
   "_id": "user1",
   "name": "Joe",
   "age": 20
}
```

**posts**

```
{
   "content": "Yo what's up!",
   "created": "2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
   "author": "user1"
}
```

I would like to create a query on the posts collection that returns the following:

```
{
       "content": "Yo what's up!",
       "created": "2018-02-05T05:00:00.000Z",
       "author": {
            "name": "Joe",
            "age": 20
}
```

Is there any way to do this in raw MongoDB? 
I'm using the MongoDB Node.js client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregation with lookup operator.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
{"$lookup":{
    "from":"users",
    "localField":"author",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"author"
}},
{"$addFields":{
    "author": {"$arrayElemAt":["$author",0]}
}}])
```

Comment: Can you explain why `$addFields` is necessary?

Comment: `$lookup` by design returns an array. Use `$addFields` to overwrite  the author array to return a single document with `$arrayElemAt` to project element at index 0.

Comment: how can I limit the resulting `user` objects to just certain fields, for example if I just wanted the `name` but not the `age` ? Is there a simple way?

Comment: You're welcome. Try project with exclusion. Something like `{$project:{"author.age":0}}` after addFields stage to drop the age field.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.posts.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $lookup: {
                "from": "user",
                "localField": "author",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "authorobj"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $project: {
                content: 1,
                created: 1,
                author: {
                    'name': {
                        "$arrayElemAt": ["$authorobj.name", 0]
                    },
                    'age': {
                        "$arrayElemAt": ["$authorobj.age", 0]
                    }
                },



            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation!